# JPA: createNativeQuery.getSingleResult() return an object, how I can get the value of one attribute inside that object

Tags: java, jpa

I have a query like this

```
SET @rownum := 0; 
SELECT rank, id, point FROM
      (
      SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id, point FROM user ORDER BY point DESC
      ) AS result
WHERE id = 0;
```

So I use `EntityManager#createNativeQuery` to execute this query.

```
Object temp = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult(); //sql is the above SQL query
```

So now object `temp` hold information about `rank`, `id`, and `point`. Note that `rank` is not an attribute inside my Entity, `rank` is calculated when the query execute --> cant cast this object to my Entity.

So how can I get the value of `rank`?

**EDIT**
**Here is the answer to what I am looking for. So instead of this**

```
Object temp = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```

Do this

```
Object[] temp = (Object [])em.createNativeQuery(sql).getSingleResult();
```

Since I want to know the value of `rank`, then I would do this

```
Long rank = (Long) temp[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

createNativeQuery method creates a Query instance. You have to invoke getResultList() or getSingleResult() on the Query object to actually execute the query.

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: ohhh my bad, the real code have all getSingleResult(). What I'm asking is how to get the attribute from my result object.

Comment: You have to cast temp object to your Entity object type then invoke getter methods from Entity object.

Comment: You can use @SqlResultSetMapping annotation to map scalar results. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I figure out. Thank you very much. I post my answer above. btw @SqlResultSetMapping seems pretty cool, thank for letting me know that